# To show that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an infinite set $B \subset A$ such that diam$(B) < \epsilon$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $A$ is an infinite subset of a totally bounded metric space $(X, d)$, then to show that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an infinite set $B \subset A$ such that diam$(B) < \epsilon$.

Finding difficulties to begin with the proof please help!

Comment: The first step should *always* be writing the definitions down, and checking they are correct against your notes.

Answer (score 0):

See the definition of the totally bounded metric space.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space